# General architectural approach to Drupal for a new project

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, 7

Thank you for taking your time to answer.
Her is the edited version:

I am developing a sport social networking website. I come from WordPress cms and for this particular project I've choosen Drupal Commons that seems more suited to me compared to wordpress solution "Buddypress".

This sport social network revolves around 3 points, along with all the features of a social network which the distribution offers(wall, comment, follow an user...)

1. Manage an activity: (nutrition/exercice program)

   - User can add/edit/delete their own activity
   - User can save an existing public activity as its own activity
2. Display of activities flow on each user wall (eg User create a training program that appears on all others users wall)

   - User can filter the display (own flow, all users flow, user groups flow)
3. Graph/summary generation of some activities and display for each user on his backend

My questions are as follows:

1. What would be the best approach for this type of project ?
2. Should I create a module for 2 activities (nutrition and programs) ?
3. Create taxonomy + custom content type ? (What would be criteria that guide to the choise of fields on taxonomy rather than custom content type?)

I see it as follows, taxonomy to structure data types and then custom content type to create custom forms that will retrieve the data entered by the users content.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I've edited the question, please considere to reopen it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to decide what the best method to store each content type will be.

You main options are Content Types, Taxonomies or custom entities.

If your data needs revisions, author information or comments that creating a custom content types would be ideal. (think articles, blogs, etc.)

If you don't need that much bolted on functionality, and just want to store a list then a taxonomy vocabulary may be more appropriate. Taxonomy terms are still easy to integrate with the views module and can also be stored with a hierarchy structure.

If you need to store something entirely different to either of these 2 options (think till data, site adverts or vehicles) then a custom entity may be more suitable. This option is more work initially however the module [Entity Construction Kit (ECK)](https://drupal.org/project/eck) makes things easier. This would be more work to integrate with Drupal views.

It is worth spending some time making sure you make the right decisions about this before you start as in the long run can save lots of time.

[This is a great article](http://www.4sitestudios.com/blog/sep-13-2013/when-use-content-types-taxonomies-and-custom-entities-drupal) that builds further on what I've said.

It sounds like quite a lot of what your building will require some fairly custom functionality so I would look down the custom entities path...

Comment: Hello,

Thanks @Felix for the helpful link and taking your time to answer.

My data will need revisions and I see activities more as a blog post with author informations, users comments...

Use of custom content type seems good in my case but I wonder how users will be able to filter on data without taxonomy among a list of about 10,000 foods.